# Get INSERT return on response

Tags: php, json

I have the following problem, I send a JSON to a PHP service
(the staff that was responsible for PHP is no longer in the company) that inserts the JSON data into the database.
The problem is that the way the PHP page is developed it returns me that the data was entered even when they are not! I need it, when something goes wrong, to show me what happened (why the insert was not done) so I can fix it.
What should I change on the PHP page so it can satisfy the question I mentioned?

This is the page

```
<?php
    $startTime = microtime(true);
    include_once("../utils/config.php");
    include_once("../utils/utils.php");
    include_once("../services/rest.utils.php");

    function reviewAluno($aluno) {
        $aluno->nome = quoteOrNull($aluno->nome);
        $aluno->rm = quoteOrNull($aluno->rm);
        $aluno->rg = quoteOrNull($aluno->rg);
        $aluno->usuario = quoteOrNull($aluno->usuario);

        $aluno->senha = quoteOrNull($aluno->senha);
        $aluno->cursoAluno = quoteOrNull($aluno->cursoAluno);
        $aluno->urlFoto = quoteOrNull($aluno->urlFoto);
        $aluno->email = quoteOrNull($aluno->email);

        $aluno->rgEscolar = quoteOrNull($aluno->rgEscolar);
        $aluno->cpf = quoteOrNull($aluno->cpf);
        $aluno->naturalidade = quoteOrNull($aluno->naturalidade);
        $aluno->nacionalidade = quoteOrNull($aluno->nacionalidade);

        $aluno->dataNascimento = formataDataIsoToMySQL($aluno->dataNascimento);
        $aluno->endereco = quoteOrNull($aluno->endereco);

        $aluno->numero = quoteOrNull($aluno->numero);
        $aluno->complemento = quoteOrNull($aluno->complemento);
        $aluno->bairro = quoteOrNull($aluno->bairro);
        $aluno->cep = quoteOrNull($aluno->cep);

        $aluno->cidade = quoteOrNull($aluno->cidade);
        $aluno->estado = quoteOrNull($aluno->estado);
        $aluno->pais = quoteOrNull($aluno->pais);
        $aluno->telefone = quoteOrNull($aluno->telefone);

        $aluno->telefoneResidencial = quoteOrNull($aluno->telefoneResidencial);
        $aluno->telefoneCelular = quoteOrNull($aluno->telefoneCelular);
        $aluno->certidaoNumero = quoteOrNull($aluno->certidaoNumero);
        $aluno->certidaoFolha = quoteOrNull($aluno->certidaoFolha);

        $aluno->certidaoLivro = quoteOrNull($aluno->certidaoLivro);
        $aluno->certidaoDistrito = quoteOrNull($aluno->certidaoDistrito);
        $aluno->certidaoCidade = quoteOrNull($aluno->certidaoCidade);
        $aluno->certidaoEstado = quoteOrNull($aluno->certidaoEstado);

        $aluno->certidaoEmissao = formataDataIsoToMySQL($aluno->certidaoEmissao);
        $aluno->certidaoHash = quoteOrNull($aluno->certidaoHash);
        $aluno->rgOrgao = quoteOrNull($aluno->rgOrgao);
        $aluno->rgDataEmissao = formataDataIsoToMySQL($aluno->rgDataEmissao);

        $aluno->religiao = quoteOrNull($aluno->religiao);
        $aluno->catraca = quoteOrNull($aluno->catraca);
        $aluno->trabalhoEmpresa = quoteOrNull($aluno->trabalhoEmpresa);
        $aluno->trabalhoTelefone = quoteOrNull($aluno->trabalhoTelefone);

        $aluno->medicamento1 = quoteOrNull($aluno->medicamento1);
        $aluno->medicamento2 = quoteOrNull($aluno->medicamento2);

        $aluno->medicamento3 = quoteOrNull($aluno->medicamento3);
        $aluno->medicamento4 = quoteOrNull($aluno->medicamento4);
        $aluno->alergia = quoteOrNull($aluno->alergia);
        $aluno->disturbioVisual = quoteOrNull($aluno->disturbioVisual);
        $aluno->disturbioAuditivo = quoteOrNull($aluno->disturbioAuditivo);

        $aluno->hospital = quoteOrNull($aluno->hospital);
        $aluno->medicoPessoal = quoteOrNull($aluno->medicoPessoal);
        $aluno->planoSaude = quoteOrNull($aluno->planoSaude);
        $aluno->restricaoAlimentar = quoteOrNull($aluno->restricaoAlimentar);

        $aluno->observacoesSaude = quoteOrNull($aluno->observacoesSaude);
        $aluno->tituloEleitor = quoteOrNull($aluno->tituloEleitor);
        $aluno->certificadoMilitar = quoteOrNull($aluno->certificadoMilitar);
        $aluno->estadoCivil = quoteOrNull($aluno->estadoCivil);

        $aluno->escolaMedio = quoteOrNull($aluno->escolaMedio);
        $aluno->escolaCidade = quoteOrNull($aluno->escolaCidade);
        $aluno->escolaEstado = quoteOrNull($aluno->escolaEstado);
        $aluno->escolaAno = quoteOrNull($aluno->escolaAno);

        $aluno->dataFalecimento = formataDataIsoToMySQL($aluno->dataFalecimento);
        $aluno->contrato = quoteOrNull($aluno->contrato);
        $aluno->ultimaAtualizacao = formataDataIsoToMySQL($aluno->ultimaAtualizacao);

        $aluno->ultimaPublicacao = formataDataIsoToMySQL($aluno->ultimaPublicacao);
        $aluno->autoRespLegal = quoteOrNull($aluno->autoRespLegal);
        $aluno->autoRespFinan = quoteOrNull($aluno->autoRespFinan);

        $aluno->podeFamiliares = quoteOrNull($aluno->podeFamiliares);
        $aluno->podeSozinho = quoteOrNull($aluno->podeSozinho);
        $aluno->podeSozinhoExtra = quoteOrNull($aluno->podeSozinhoExtra);

        $aluno->podeEsperarFora = quoteOrNull($aluno->podeEsperarFora);
        $aluno->validadeAcesso = formataDataIsoToMySQL($aluno->validadeAcesso);
    }

    $body = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $list = carregaCorpo($body);

        if (signatureCheck($body)) {
        $tableAluno = getTabela("Aluno");
        $cta = 0;
        $database = conectaDatabase();
        $script = '';
        foreach ($list as $aluno) { 
            reviewAluno($aluno);

            $sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM {$tableAluno} WHERE alunoID = {$aluno->alunoID};";
            $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO {$tableAluno} ";
            $sqlInsert .= '(alunoID, nome, rm, rg, usuario, senha, cursoAluno, urlFoto, email, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' rgEscolar, cpf, naturalidade, nacionalidade, sexo, raca, dataNascimento, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' endereco, numero, complemento, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, pais, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' telefone, telefoneResidencial, telefoneCelular, certidaoNumero, certidaoFolha, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' certidaoLivro, certidaoDistrito, certidaoCidade, certidaoEstado, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' certidaoEmissao, certidaoHash, rgOrgao, rgDataEmissao, religiao, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' catraca, trabalhoEmpresa, trabalhoTelefone,';
            $sqlInsert .= ' medicamento1, medicamento2, medicamento3, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' medicamento4, alergia, desmaio, vacinas, disturbioVisual, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' disturbioAuditivo, acidente, hospital, medicoPessoal, planoSaude, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' restricaoAlimentar, observacoesSaude, tituloEleitor, certificadoMilitar, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' estadoCivil, escolaMedio, escolaCidade, escolaEstado, escolaAno, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' dataFalecimento, contrato, ultimaAtualizacao, ultimaPublicacao, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' autoRespLegal, autoRespFinan, podeFamiliares, podeSozinho, ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' podeSozinhoExtra, podeEsperarFora, validadeAcesso) ';
            $sqlInsert .= ' VALUES ( ';
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->alunoID}, {$aluno->nome}, {$aluno->rm}, {$aluno->rg}, {$aluno->usuario}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->senha}, {$aluno->cursoAluno}, {$aluno->urlFoto}, {$aluno->email}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->rgEscolar}, {$aluno->cpf}, {$aluno->naturalidade}, {$aluno->nacionalidade}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->sexo}, {$aluno->raca}, {$aluno->dataNascimento}, {$aluno->endereco}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->numero}, {$aluno->complemento}, {$aluno->bairro}, {$aluno->cep}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->cidade}, {$aluno->estado}, {$aluno->pais}, {$aluno->telefone}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->telefoneResidencial}, {$aluno->telefoneCelular}, {$aluno->certidaoNumero}, {$aluno->certidaoFolha}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->certidaoLivro}, {$aluno->certidaoDistrito}, {$aluno->certidaoCidade}, {$aluno->certidaoEstado}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->certidaoEmissao}, {$aluno->certidaoHash}, {$aluno->rgOrgao}, {$aluno->rgDataEmissao}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->religiao}, {$aluno->catraca}, {$aluno->trabalhoEmpresa}, {$aluno->trabalhoTelefone}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->medicamento1}, {$aluno->medicamento2}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->medicamento3}, {$aluno->medicamento4}, {$aluno->alergia}, {$aluno->desmaio}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->vacinas}, {$aluno->disturbioVisual}, {$aluno->disturbioAuditivo}, {$aluno->acidente}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->hospital}, {$aluno->medicoPessoal}, {$aluno->planoSaude}, {$aluno->restricaoAlimentar}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->observacoesSaude}, {$aluno->tituloEleitor}, {$aluno->certificadoMilitar}, {$aluno->estadoCivil}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->escolaMedio}, {$aluno->escolaCidade}, {$aluno->escolaEstado}, {$aluno->escolaAno}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->dataFalecimento}, {$aluno->contrato}, {$aluno->ultimaAtualizacao}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->ultimaPublicacao}, {$aluno->autoRespLegal}, {$aluno->autoRespFinan}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->podeFamiliares}, {$aluno->podeSozinho}, {$aluno->podeSozinhoExtra}, ";
            $sqlInsert .= " {$aluno->podeEsperarFora}, {$aluno->validadeAcesso} ";
            $sqlInsert .= ");";

            sqlExecute($database, $sqlDelete);
            sqlExecute($database, $sqlInsert);


            $script .= $sqlDelete . "\n"; 
            $script .= $sqlInsert . "\n";
            $cta++;
        }
        desconectaDB($database);
        $description = "{$cta} alunos foram registrados";
        $status = "200";

        salvaScript($script, 'alunos');
    } else {
        $description = "não autorizado";
        $status = "401";
    }

    $endTime = microtime(true);
    $timeSpent = $endTime - $startTime;

    echo "{\"status\":{$status}, \"descricao\":\"$description\", \"timeSpent\": \"{$timeSpent}\"}";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, you may need to learn basic php to correct your code. you need to validate each parameter to have a value, that way you can restrict your query not to insert when it is empty value.

Comment: The reason might be the data which is inserted contains some strings which are not enclosed in quotes.

Comment: I think this could be handled from the `sqlExecute` function, wherever that's defined (I would search for it in one of your imports). Looking that up could help. It could potentially be returning a bool value indicating whether the sql statement succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Find the code that defines `function sqlExecute()` (I'm guessing it's in `utils.php`) and the line where it runs `mysql_query()` (just a guess; there are now several better ways to do this but this code looks ancient so that's what it probably does).

Make sure that `sqlExecute()` returns the return value of `mysql_query()`, which is a boolean for success.

Save the outcome of both queries in a variable:

```
        $success = sqlExecute($database, $sqlDelete);
        $success = $success && sqlExecute($database, $sqlInsert);
```

Then use `$success` in an `if` condition to decide whether to return the JSON for "success" or a different JSON message for "error".

(Sidenote: This entire script is a horror show, and should ideally be thrown away and rewritten, but that's a different topic.)